# How to recreate this image using CSS-Position

Tags: css, position

I have to recreate the image in the end of this question using positioning. I am not allowed to edit the HTML in any way. I don't want to know the solution but rather what am I missing or overlooking. I'm positive this has to be done with `position: absolute` but I'm not sure how to target each box individually.

This is the code:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Mansalva', cursive;
    position: absolute;
}

div {
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

p {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div><p>Your Name</p></div>
</body>
```

[image: Desired position of each element]

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: CSs-Grid would be the ideal method.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the link, I'm not entirely sure this needs to be done with absolute or relative or both but this is supposed to be an exercise in positioning.

Comment: @Paulie_D Interesting, I'll take a look at Grid! Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

To do this only with css, you have to use selectors.

For example :

```
/* Selects the second <li> element in a list */
li:nth-child(2) {
    color: lime;
}

/* Selects every fourth element
among any group of siblings */
:nth-child(4n) {
    color: lime;
}
```

The [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) is very well done.

Without touching HTML and without adding JS, I think CSS selectors are mandatory.

Another [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to help you

You can use CSS selectors to target a specific div and a CSS grid for positioning

Comment: Thank you very much! I completely forgot about nth-child selectors. This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Cpt_Gizmo You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark if this helped you :D